# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I have already build all the required jars but still getting this exception.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please indicate the versions of the tools you are trying to make work together.

Answer (score 1):

`EhCacheRegionFactory` is in `ehcache-core` jar. The only way to get this exception is if this jar isn't in your classpath.